# How do I create custom calendar in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type bookings with custom fields in it. I want to plot the dates to a calendar only in the administrator backend.

Is it possible to create that? Just like vue-event-calendar right here -> http://geoffzhu.cn/vue-event-calendar/

How do I create it just like that in the WordPress admin backend?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following one. It's a WordPress plug-in.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

Comment: Can I plot the dates from my custom post type?
(sample: booking1 - june 10,  booking2 - june 11,  booking3 - june 12)
Can I plot that 3 dates on the calendar?

Comment: yes it's super easy ,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0okrUs-xOq4
here's a video that explains how it works

Comment: What I mean is a calendar to be displayed on the admin side, not on the frontend